# xhr upload progress event only firing once

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain

I want to update a progress bar using the xhr progress event.

I have the following code:

```
  xhr: function() {
    var xhr = Ember.$.ajaxSettings.xhr();
    xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(e){
      if (e.lengthComputable) {
        self.didProgress(e);
      }
    }, false);
    return xhr;
  },
```

The problem is that the event only happens once and I believe this happening because the server call is cross domain.

Does anybody know what I have to set on the server by way of headers to let this work correctly?

Comment: Nothing that you wouldn't normally have to return in a server response to a cross origin request.  If you are unfamiliar with the process, have you seen https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this has nothing to do with being a cross-domain request. Normally, on Apache, you wouldn't get a progress event to fire more then once because (I assume) you upload the whole file in one chunk. This is the normal behavior without using a module like [apache-upload-progress-module](https://github.com/drogus/apache-upload-progress-module)

The way I achieved this without modules in the past is to split the file into chunks on the client-side (using the File API and Blobs). The first chunk gets sent, waits for the server response, sends the second chunk from where it left off, and so on until there are no more chunks to upload.

There are a few examples of this around the web. You might want to take a look at how [JQuery File Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) does it.

I hope this helps.